# tree parser vs stream parser

Tags: android, parsing, battery

Looking for an explanation on tree parser vs stream parser.

From what i have been researching the JSON build-in parser in android is a tree parser and the Jackson Json parser is a stream parser.  Also, android's xml pull parser is a stream parser.

My question is what is  a tree parser and could you explain the difference between a stream and tree parser?  From Google I/O presenter mentioned tree parser hog much more battery life and should be avoided in place of a stream parser.

UPDATE: Is tree parser equal to Dom parser? I mean are the terms the same?

Comment: in short: tree parser will load whole data and parse it, stream parser will do it in chunks and forward only(in tree parser you can have access to all elements - in stream only to current) ... i don't know how it is connected with battery life but stream parsers "eat" less memory

Comment: Is tree parser equal to Dom parser? I mean are the terms the same?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A tree parser returns a complete parse of the text. Therefore, it doesn't give an answer until the entire text has been parsed.

In contrast, a stream parser returns information as it is processing the text. It is up to you then to build a tree if you so choose. In algorithms, this difference is the difference between what is called a batch or off-line algorithm (tree parsing) versus an on-line algorithm (stream parser).

See [What's the difference between an on-line and off-line algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11496013/what-is-the-difference-between-an-on-line-and-off-line-algorithm).

So why would you choose one versus the other? The Google I/O presenter mentioned battery life. But that's a result of the more general principle you need more memory for storing a tree for the entire text and more processing time to read the entire text (assuming the stream parser can quit early).

If you are looking for specific information that uses a small part of the text such as finding the first tag in a DOM or an XML document, then the stream approach is probably the way to go.

If on the other hand you need to find *all* tags, and tags of various sorts which you might think of as several conceptual passes over the document, or if you'll come back to that text/tree over and over again, then you might want do the parsing once and work off of the resulting tree rather than make several passes over the text.

Similarly if the kind of information you need is best answered by thinking about the problem as a tree: getting or passing information from children nodes, sibling nodes, and/or ancestor nodes, then you'll probably want to go the tree approach. But...

In theory you can always turn a streaming parser into a tree parser by doing the work to build the tree as you go along. And that's extra code you have to write.

The difference between a stream parser and a tree parser is like the difference between a Python iterator/generator versus a list (equivalently a Ruby enumeration versus an array).

Comment: would you say that json parsing is always tree parsing ? and xml can either be tree parsing or stream parsing ? i cant visualize json being parsed as a stream so i want to conclude its always tree parsing.

Comment: A tree parser, especially the fast ones, often create its tree reading sequentially (or stream-like) from input. It just doesn't have to run a callback along the way. Stream vs. tree then is more about the operations that are needed to be provided than whether the text is read sequentially.